# Como alinhar campos formulário em HTML

Tags: html, formulário

Oi, estou desenvolvendo um formulário em HTML. 
Gostaria de saber como posso alinhar as caixas de texto para preencher?

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <form>
    <title>Formulário</title>
    
    </img src "C:/Users\ASUS/Desktop/APRESENTAÇÃO/images"
    width="50" height="50"/>
    </p>
    
    <table border>
    
    <h1><b>Recrutamento e Seleção</b></h1>
    
    <table border>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Vaga Pretendida:</label></td>
    <td><input type=text name=vaga maxlength=26 size=23>
    <td>Data de Seleção:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Pretensão Salarial:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=pretensao maxlength=8 size=6>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <tr>
    <td>Nome:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=nomecompleto maxlength=90 size=97>
    <br>
    </table border>
    
    <table border>
    <td>RG:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=rg maxlength=15 size=20>
    <td>Data de Expedição:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>CPF:</td>
    <td><input type=TEXT name=cpf maxlength=11 size=31 >
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    <tr>
    <table border>
    <td>Sexo:
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="sexo" VALUE="Feminino">Feminino
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="sexo" VALUE="Masculino">Masculino </td>
    
                               <td>Estado Civil:</td>
                               <td> <select name="estado civil"> 
                                                                <option value="value" selected></option>
                   <option value="value1">Solteiro(a)</option>               
                   <option value="value2" >Casado(a)</option>
                   <option value="value3">União Estável</option>
                   <option value="value4">Divorciado(a)</option> 
                   <option value="value5">Viúvo(a)</option>
          </select></td>
    <td>Data de Nascimento </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="da" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ms" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="an" size="1" maxlength="4" value="">
    </td>
    </table>
    </tr>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Nome do pai:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=nomepai maxlength=89 size=89>
    <tr>
    
    <td>Nome da mãe:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=nomemae maxlength=89 size=89>
    </table></tr>
    
    <table border>
    <tr>
    <td>Telefone:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=fone maxlength=11 size=15></td> 
    <td>Celular:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=cel maxlength=11 size=15></td>   
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type=text name=email maxlength=35 size=30></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
         <td>Endereço:</td>
         <td><input type name=endereco maxlength=50 size=45></td>
         <td>Número:</td>  
         <td><input type=text name=numero maxlength=6 size=5></td>
         </table> 
    <table border>     
         <td>Complemento</td>
                        <td><input type=text name=complemento maxlength=12 size=10></td>    
                       <td>Bairro:</td>
                       <td><input type=text name=CEP maxlength=35 size=30></td>
           <td>Cep</td>
                        <td><input type=text name=cep maxlength=5 size=3> - <input type=text name=cep size=1 maxlength=3>
         <br>
         </table>
         
         <table border>
    <td>Cidade:</td>
                        <td><input type=text name=cidade maxlength=30 size=22></td>
    
                                                                <td>Estado:</td>
                                                                <td> <select name="estado"> 
                                                                <option value="valor" selected></option>
                   <option value="valor1">AC</option>               
                   <option value="valor2" >AL</option>
                   <option value="valor3">AP</option>
                   <option value="valor4">AM</option> 
                   <option value="valor5">BA</option>
                   <option value="valor6">CE</option>
                   <option value="valor7">DF</option>
                   <option value="valor8">ES</option>
                   <option value="valor9">GO</option> 
                   <option value="valor10">MA</option>
                   <option value="valor11">MT</option>
                   <option value="valor12">MS</option>
                   <option value="valor13">MG</option>
                   <option value="valor14">PA</option> 
                   <option value="valor15">PB</option>
                   <option value="valor16">PE</option>
                   <option value="valor17">PR</option>
                   <option value="valor18">PI</option>
                   <option value="valor19">RJ</option> 
                   <option value="valor20">RN</option>
                   <option value="valor21">RS</option>
                   <option value="valor22">RO</option>
                   <option value="valor23">RR</option>
                   <option value="valor24">SC</option>
                   <option value="valor25">SP</option>
                   <option value="valor26">SE</option>
                   <option value="valor27">TO</option>
                   
                   
                                   </select></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <tr>
    
    <h3>RESPONDA</h3>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Possui disponibilidade de horário <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="horario" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="horario" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
     <td>Se <b>NÃO</b>, informar o período: <br>
    Matutino<input type=checkbox name=matut value=1>
           Vespertino<input type=checkbox name=vesper value=2>
    Noturno<input type=checkbox name=notur value=3></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Início Imediato: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="inicio" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="inicio" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Residência: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="resid" VALUE="Pr">Própria
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="resid" VALUE="Al">Alugada </td>
    <td>Valor do Aluguel:<br> 
         <input type=text name=alug maxlength=8 size=15></td>
         </table> 
    
    <table border>
    <td>Reside com quantas pessoas:  <br>
         <input type=text name=resid maxlength=4 size=25></td>  
    <td>Renda Familiar:<br> 
         <input type=text name=renda maxlength=8 size=13></td>
         <td>Filhos/Dependentes: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="filho" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="filho" VALUE="Não">Não </td>         
    <td>Se <b>SIM</b>, qual a idade:<br>  
         <input type=text name=resid maxlength=25 size=35></td>
         </table>
    
    <table border>     
    <td>Possui Veículo Próprio:<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="vec" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="vec" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Qual veículo? <br> 
         <input type=text name=renda maxlength=15 size=12></td>
    <td>Dirige na rodovia:<br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="vec" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="vec" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    </table>     
    
    <h3> INFORMAÇÕES PARA SAÚDE OCUPACIONAL </h3>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Tabagista: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="tab" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="tab" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Ingestão de bebida alcóolica: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ing" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="ing" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Uso de medicamento: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="med" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="med" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Nome do Medicamento <br> 
         <input type=text name=renda maxlength=42 size=40></td>
         </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Acidente de trabalho: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="acidente" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="acidente" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Cirurgia: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="cirurgia" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="cirurgia" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    <td>Afastamento pelo INSS: <br>
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="inss" VALUE="Sim">Sim
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="inss" VALUE="Não">Não </td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    Em caso de Acidente, cirurgia ou afastamento, comente:<br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea>
    </table>
    
    <h3> INFORMAÇÕES PROFISSIONAIS</h3>
    
    <h4> Empregos Anteriores</h4>
    <h4><i> Último</i> </h4>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Empresa<br>
    <input type=text name=empresa maxlength=80 size=77>
    </table></td>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Função <br>
    <input type=text name=function maxlength=50 size=47></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Data Admissão:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Data Demissão:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Motivo da saída<br>
    <input type=text name=motivo maxlength=26 size=23></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Último Salário<br>
    <input type=text name=salario maxlength=8 size=7> </td>
    <td>Benefícios Recebidos<br>
    <input type=text name=benefi maxlength=26 size=23></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Qtde de funcionários equipe <br>
    <input type=text name=funcionario maxlength=4 size=3></td>
    <td>Maior dificuldade encontrada<<br>
    <input type=text name=dificult maxlength=20 size=15></td>
    <td>Qtde de refeições<br>
    <input type=text name=refei maxlength=6 size=6></td>
    <td>Nome Supervisor/Gerente<br>
    <input type=text name=namesup maxlength=10 size=9></td>
    </table>
    
    </table border>
    <td> Informações que julgue necessário comentar: <br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea> </td>
    </table>                                                                  
    
    <h4><i>Penúltimo</i> </h4>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Empresa<br>
    <input type=text name=empresa maxlength=80 size=77>
    </table></td>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Função<br>
    <input type=text name=function maxlength=50 size=47></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Data Admissão:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Data Demissão:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Motivo da saída<br>
    <input type=text name=motivo maxlength=26 size=23></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Último Salário<br>
    <input type=text name=salario maxlength=8 size=7> </td>
    <td>Benefícios Recebidos<br>
    <input type=text name=benefi maxlength=26 size=23></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Qtde de funcionários equipe <br>
    <input type=text name=funcionario maxlength=4 size=3></td>
    <td>Maior dificuldade encontrada<br>
    <input type=text name=dificult maxlength=20 size=15></td>
    <td>Qtde de refeições<br>
    <input type=text name=refei maxlength=6 size=6></td>
    <td>Nome Supervisor/Gerente<br>
    <input type=text name=namesup maxlength=10 size=9></td>
    </table>
    
    </table border>
    <td> Informações que julgue necessário comentar: <br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea> </td>
    </table>                                                                  
    
    <h4><i>Antepenúltimo</i> </h4>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Empresa<br>
    <input type=text name=empresa maxlength=80 size=77>
    </table></td>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Função<br>
    <input type=text name=function maxlength=50 size=47></td>
    </table>
    <table border>
    <td>Data Admissão:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Data Demissão:<br>
    <input type="text" name="dia" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="mes" size="1" maxlength="2" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="ano" size="1" maxlength="4" value=""> </td>
    <td>Motivo da saída<br>
    <input type=text name=motivo maxlength=26 size=23></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Último Salário<br>
    <input type=text name=salario maxlength=8 size=7> </td>
    <td>Benefícios Recebidos<br>
    <input type=text name=benefi maxlength=26 size=23></td>
    </table>
    
    <table border>
    <td>Qtde de funcionários equipe <br>
    <input type=text name=funcionario maxlength=4 size=3></td>
    <td>Maior dificuldade encontrada<br>
    <input type=text name=dificult maxlength=20 size=15></td>
    <td>Qtde de refeições<br>
    <input type=text name=refei maxlength=6 size=6></td>
    <td>Nome Supervisor/Gerente<br>
    <input type=text name=namesup maxlength=10 size=9></td>
    </table>
    
    </table border>
    <td> Informações que julgue necessário comentar: <br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea> </td>
    </table>                                                                  
    
    <h3> COMENTE </h3>
    
    </table border>
    <td> Fale sobre seus pontos <b>FORTES</b> e pontos <b>FRACOS</b>. <br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea> </td>
    </table>    
    <br>             
    
    </table border>
    <td> Quais os objetivos para sua vida pessoal? <br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea> </td>
    </table>                 
    <br>
    </table border>
    <td> Porque esta empresa deveria te contratar? <br>
    <textarea name=comentario rows=5 cols=50></textarea> </td>
    </table>                 
    
    <br>
    
    <input type="submit" value ="Enviar">
    
    <input type="reset" ="cancelar">
    
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: O que você não está conseguindo alinhar? monstre-nos o que você já fez em HTML, caso você esteja com dúvidas de como começar leia esse link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Meu_primeiro_formulario_HTML

Comment: Boa! Vi que você acresceu o HTML a pergunta, agora poderia especificar como você deseja alinhar seu formulário?

Comment: Eu odeio usar table para alinhar elementos ou formulários. É horrível de se trabalhar em vários formatos de tela. Principalmente celular. Recomendo fortemente o uso da propriedade display: inline-block; fica muito mais fácil de trabalhar a quebra de layout para vários tamanhos de tela.

Comment: Que tipo de alinhamento vc deseja?

Answer (score -1):

Cara, não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer mas vamos lá.

Se você quer tirar a coluna entre o input e a label, basta usar o atributo colspan na coluna da label, por exemplo.
Veja documento: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Já se for apenas alinhamento mesmo, na TD tem um atributo `align` que você pode setar como `left, right ou center`. Ou até, com css, pode usar o `float:left`, etc. No próprio input.

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta.